# Element type is invalid - Export default and default import

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-test-renderer

I'm writing tests for my components, the components work fine in the application. Importing and consuming them works great but getting them to work with `react-test-renderer` has not been as great. For example, I have a social component that reads config and renders out links.

./components/Social/social.js

```js
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

import config from '../../../content/meta/config'

import GithubIcon from '!svg-react-loader!../../images/svg-icons/github.svg?name=GithubIcon'
import LinkedInIcon from '!svg-react-loader!../../images/svg-icons/linkedin.svg?name=LinkedInIcon'
import TwitterIcon from '!svg-react-loader!../../images/svg-icons/twitter.svg?name=TwitterIcon'
import InstagramIcon from '!svg-react-loader!../../images/svg-icons/instagram.svg?name=InstagramIcon'
import DevIcon from '!svg-react-loader!../../images/svg-icons/dev.svg?name=DevIcon'

const Social = props => {
  const { theme } = props
  const items = config.authorSocialLinks
  const icons = {
    twitter: TwitterIcon,
    github: GithubIcon,
    linkedin: LinkedInIcon,
    instagram: InstagramIcon,
    dev: DevIcon,
  }

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div className="social">
        {items.map(item => {
          const Icon = icons[item.name]
          return (
            <a
              href={item.url}
              key={item.name}
              className="socialLink"
              target="_blank"
              rel="noopener noreferrer"
              title={item.name}
            >
              <Icon className="svg" />
            </a>
          )
        })}
      </div>

      {/* --- STYLES --- */}
      <style jsx global>
        {`
          @media screen and (max-width: 450px) {
            .social {
              width: 95%;
            }
          }
          @media screen and (min-width: 450px) {
            .social {
              width: 40%;
            }
          }
          .social {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            margin: 0 auto;
            padding: 20px;

            :global(svg) {
              width: 30px;
              height: 30px;
              transition: all 0.5s;
            }

            &:hover :global(svg) {
              fill: ${theme.color.special.attention};
            }
          }

          .svg path {
            fill: ${theme.color.brand.primary};
          }

          .socialLink {
            margin: 0 auto;
            display: inline-block;
            padding: 1px;
            text-align: center;
          }
        `}
      </style>
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}

Social.propTypes = {
  theme: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
}

export default Social
```

./components/Social/index.js

```js
export { default } from './Social'
```

In my test I'm importing the component and rendering to do snapshot testing. Test:

./components/**tests**/social.spec.js

```js
import React from 'react'
import { create } from 'react-test-renderer'
import Social from '../Social'
const theme = require('../../theme/theme.json')

describe('Social Component', () => {
  it('renders correctly', () => {
    const tree = create(<Social theme={theme} />).toJSON()
    expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot()
  })
})
```

I am getting the error only in my test and not in the app.

> Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
>
> Check the render method of `Social`.

I've tried many little tweaks to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When running jest your entire build system doesn't exist - in this case webpack. So imports like this `'!svg-react-loader!../../images/svg-icons/github.svg?name=GithubIcon'` will throw an error (or in your case maybe return undefined?).

You need to run jest in a webpack context if you want those - https://jestjs.io/docs/en/webpack

Comment: Ran into that issue before I'm actually using the `jest-svg-transformer` in the `jest.config.js` to resolve the issue, can confirm it throws an error.

Comment: I spent more time with this solution and it ended up being the culprit the transformer and file mocks that I was doing wasn't enough. I changed to use `react-icon/fa` instead of local svgs and got it working. Thank you Alon Bar David!

Answer (score 1):

I imagine the test runner is getting confused over the export default in the barrel index.js file.

Two things to try:

Change index.js to

```
import Social from './Social'
export {
 social
};
```

Or,

If you are going to ultimately use named exports, why not just do so from the start? Change Social to export `export const Social = props => {...}` and in your index file `export * from './Social`

Comment: Thanks for your reply, unfortunately, all result in the same error which is why I think it may not actually be an issue with the exporting/importing of components and something larger. Here is my repository if you want to take a look: [link](https://github.com/chrisotto6/chrisottodev) . Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

```
export { default as Social } from './Social'
```

Can you try it out like in the code snippet above?

I also see that you try to import your Social component wrong in social.spec.js

Shouldn't it be `import Social from '../components/Social'`?
You try to import it like `import Social from '../Social'`

Comment: Thanks for the response, I did try your code snippet and it still didn't work. Like I said everything works fine for React when actually running the application it's getting it working with `react-test-renderer` that's been painful. I also updated the code in my post to include the `components` directory which is above tests. Thanks again!